# Get Edge Version for Azure AD users

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-activedirectory

I am trying to get the version of Microsoft Edge installed on all Azure AD user computers in my domain. So far, I have the following script, which I think should work, but it keeps returning unauthorized errors for each user it lists in the output.

```
# Set your application (client) ID, tenant ID, and client secret
$clientId = "client id goes here"
$tenantId = "tenant id goes here"
$clientSecret = "secret goes here"

# Get an access token for the Microsoft Graph API
$uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"
$body = @{
    grant_type = "client_credentials"
    client_id = $clientId
    client_secret = $clientSecret
    scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Body $body
$accessToken = $response.access_token

# Get all users in the domain
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"
$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $accessToken"
}
$users = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $headers).value

# Get the Edge version for each user
$edgeVersions = @()
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/$($user.id)/devices"
    $devices = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $headers).value

    foreach ($device in $devices) {
        if ($device.deviceOSType -eq "Windows") {
            $edgeVersion = $device.additionalProperties.'msedge_version'
            if ($edgeVersion) {
                $edgeVersions += [PSCustomObject]@{
                    User = $user.displayName
                    Device = $device.displayName
                    EdgeVersion = $edgeVersion
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

# Display the Edge versions
$edgeVersions | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

I am getting the ID's from here:

[image: Screenshot showing the ID's used]

I have given and azure app the following permissions (probably more than needed):

[image: Screenshot showing assigned permissions]

I load powershell by right clicking and selecting <kbd>Run As Administrator</kbd>.

It still says `[Invoke-RestMethod is unauthorized]`.

I clearly am missing some permissions somewhere, but I do not know where.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked that the returned access token is correct?

Answer (score 1):

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/userID/devices` is deprecated per [this documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-devices?view=graph-rest-beta) so it won't return any data regardless of permissions. I'm unaware of an attribute that replaced the `msedge_version` property.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you do get all the users with your query, the token should be OK, and I think that permissions are okay as well.
Like mentioned by @Crimsonfox, the **option to list user devices is deprecated**.

You can test your queries here, where you can also see what kind of options are available:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

I did some testing and I also receive a 401 error (`Unauthorized - 401 - 887ms`) when executing `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/Devices`.
When trying with a used ID `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/6e7b768e-07e2-4810-8459-485f84f8f204/managedDevices`, the API returns error 400 - bad request.

[image: Unauthorized error]

I came across [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/userteamwork-list-installedapps?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) that returns installed apps, but I wasn't able to find any information on Microsoft Edge and how to get its version. The query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/teamwork/installedApps?$expand=teamsAppDefinition
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is with the request
`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/userID/devices`,
there might be an alternative.

The Microsoft article
[List owned Devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-owneddevices?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=powershell)
suggests this code:

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Users

# A UPN can also be used as -UserId.
Get-MgUserOwnedDevice -UserId $userId
```

An example of a response is given in the article, although I suppose
that it relates more to the HTTP variant of this command:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: application/json

{
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "id-value"
    }
  ]
}
```

Once you have the id, the device itself could perhaps
be retrieved by using the
[Get-MgDevice command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.identity.directorymanagement/get-mgdevice?view=graph-powershell-1.0).

Reference :
[Get-MgUserOwnedDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.users/get-mguserowneddevice?view=graph-powershell-1.0).